# MongoDB Pagination - Total count of results while using Limits and Skips? (Filter Array)

Tags: mongodb, pagination

I need to know the total amount of rows/documents my searchquery contains for creating the pagination.

This is the code:

```
         $filter= ['$text' => ['$search' => $code] ,'countries_tags' => 'en:' . strtolower($langs_list[$this->page->lang][3])];
         $options = array('limit'=>$limit, 'skip'=>$skip,'sort'=>['images'=>-1]); //'sort'=>['images'=>-1]
         $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
         $cursor = $this->mongoDB->executeQuery('off.products', $query);

         $this->results = array();
         foreach ($cursor as $document) {
            $this->results[] =  $document;
         }


      $this->rows_found = 300;// How can I get the correct number of hits??
```

$this->results[] only contains the specific page total amount of rows/documents, but the search itself might contain 300, 500 or even 1000 results and I want to know how many real results there was.

Is there a simple parameter I just need to throw into this query to get the number of total results ?

I have tried pretty much everything. But what I find when I search for PHP and MongoDB is method calls for this filtering but the entire code I have "taken over" uses arrays for sending in the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

$facet is suitable for the case:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 "$facet": {
  "total": [
    {
      // your query
    },
    {
      "$count": "pages"
    }
  ],
  "current_page": [
    {
      // your query
    },
    {
      $skip: 1
    },
    {
      $limit: 2
    }
  ]
 }
}
])
```

Explained:

Send you query to 1st facet where you can skip & limit and same query to 2nd facet element with {$count}  stage so in same aggregation to receive the total documents as well.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LUa-MQ6pwIK)